# Merge two plots so that coloring of series coincides in a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put two plots one on top of another. Both of these plots share the same X and Y axis. The only difference is that the first plot is a barplot, and the second one is line chart.

```
library("ggplot2")

p1 <- ggplot(result_a, aes(x=type,y=as.numeric(num_excluded),fill=as.factor(year),width=.5)) +   
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()

p1 <- p1 + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Legend:")) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") 


p2 <- ggplot(result_a, aes(x=type,y=as.numeric(total),
                           group=as.factor(year),color=as.factor(year),
                           width=.5)) +   
  geom_line()+geom_point()+
  coord_flip()
```

How can I put them together so that the COLORS of lines and bars coincide (i.e. the interpretation of colors given in a legend refers to both lines and bars)?

**Update:**

`dput(result_a)`

```
structure(list(year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012), type = c("AAA", "BBB", "AAA","BBB", "AAA"), num_excluded = c(5, 2, 4, 15, 2), total = c(100,20,500,300,100)))
```

Comment: can you post a `dput(result_a)`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048002/represent-geom-line-and-geom-bar-in-the-same-plot) might help. For the colours, you should be able to set them manually to an identical palette.

Comment: @MikeyMike: Done.

Comment: @Haboryme: Thanks but I haven't found the solution of the coloring problem in this thread. Did I mistunderstand sth?

Comment: @cuttlefish44: They have same measure units, but p2 has greater values of y than p1. So, the lines of p2 will finally apprear on top of p1 (or more to the right if using `coord_flip()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this?

```
ggplot(result_a) +   
    geom_bar(aes(x = type, y = as.numeric(num_excluded),
                 fill = as.factor(year), width=.5), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(aes(x = type, y = as.numeric(total),
                  group = as.factor(year), color = as.factor(year),
                  width = .5), size = 2) +
    coord_flip()+ 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Legend:")) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Marta. However, I want to merge these charts on a single plot. As a result the lines of p2 will apear on top of p1 (or more to the right, if using `coord_flip()`. Do you know hw to do it?

Comment: @FiofanS, I've edited my answer. Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Just a small detail: I also wanted to share the legend and its colors. Is it possible to use 1 legend that corresponds to both charts?

Comment: @FiofanS, I've edited once again. I've just deleted one legend with `guide = FALSE`.